# Translating a piece of js to asp.net (regex involved)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I'm moving a piece of our programming code from client side to server side because of performance issues (note: not all code is in the post, just the part i'm having trouble with)

the specific piece i'm having trouble with is a piece of alias rewriting. Can somebody help me translating this part.

```
    //1. Force UperCamelCase: "Een lange financiele 443 naam" -> "Een Lange Financiele 443 Naam"
    var strTempAlias = this.strName.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (match) { return match.toUpperCase() });

    //2. Only allow a-zA-Z chars. "Een Lange Financiele 443 Naam" -> "EenLangeFinancieleNaam"
    strTempAlias = strTempAlias.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');

    //3. Until max length 25: progressive remove small characters: "EenLangeFinaNaam"
    var intShrinkSize = 10
    while (strTempAlias.length > 25 && intShrinkSize > 3) {
        var r = new RegExp("([A-Z]+[a-z]{0," + intShrinkSize + "})([a-z]+)", "g")
        strTempAlias = strTempAlias.replace(r, function (match, $1, $2) { return $1 });
        intShrinkSize -= 2;
    }
```

I've been able to convert steps 1 and 2 to .net code, but i can't figure out how to convert step 3.

Below you can find the converted versions in vb.net and c# (for me it doesn't matter which version is answered i can program both)

VB.NET

```
        '1. Force UperCamelCase: "Een lange financiele 443 naam" -> "Een Lange Financiele 443 Naam"
        Dim strTempAlias As String = StrConv(strAlias, VbStrConv.ProperCase)

        '2. Only allow a-zA-Z chars. "Een Lange Financiele 443 Naam" -> "EenLangeFinancieleNaam"
        strTempAlias = Regex.Replace(strTempAlias, "[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "")

        '3. Until max length 25: progressive remove small characters: "EenLangeFinaNaam"
        Dim shrinksize = 10
        While strTempAlias.Length > 25 AndAlso shrinksize > 3
            'last piece of code to translate
        End While
```

C#

```
//1. Force UperCamelCase: "Een lange financiele 443 naam" -> "Een Lange Financiele 443 Naam"
string strTempAlias = Strings.StrConv(strAlias, VbStrConv.ProperCase);

//2. Only allow a-zA-Z chars. "Een Lange Financiele 443 Naam" -> "EenLangeFinancieleNaam"
strTempAlias = Regex.Replace(strTempAlias, "[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "");

//3. Until max length 25: progressive remove small characters: "EenLangeFinaNaam"
dynamic shrinksize = 10;
while (strTempAlias.Length > 25 && shrinksize > 3) {
    //last piece of code to translate
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int intShrinkSize = 10;
while (strTempAlias.Length > 25 && shrinksize > 3) {
   strTempAlias = Regex.Replace(strTempAlias, "([A-Z]+[a-z]{0," + intShrinkSize + "})([a-z]+)", "$1");
   intShrinkSize -= 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes my problem